Baskervald Package Produces Slightly Different Italicized Textgreek
I am typesetting a document which contains some Greek.
For example,

Regarding the first Greek word:
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{baskervald}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge

\textgreek{s{\~{w}}ma}

\textit{\textgreek{$\sigma${\~{w}}ma}}
\end{document}

with the output

So, it would seem that italicizing the textgreek produces what I want.
But alas, if I rerun the code, only this time, invoking the baskervald package, something different occurs: the displayed italicized a reverts back to an alpha:

How may I produce the first set of output using the baskervald package?

why are you using $\sigma$ for greek text? baskervald does not affect greek. however, it does change the default text encoding from ot1 to t1. neither supports greek.

@cfr I had tried many pedestrian things prior to posting the question. It seems like it was not the best MWE to post. Sorry for the confusion.

you'd see the same effect if you loaded any other font which doesn't support greek, which is true for a lot of fonts :-). you need the LGR encoding here. cm has fonts setup for that, but baskervald doesn't. if the font included greek, the package would probably support the needed encoding, but it wouldn't be appropriate to impose the choice of another font on users who might want to pair baskervald with something else.

Baskervaldx doesn't support Greek. Indeed, you get
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/ybv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LGR/ybv/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LGR/ybv/m/n' instead on input line 8.

and the first warning is the most important.
You can substitute.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{baskervald}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\familydefault}{bodoni}


\begin{document}

Text in English \textgreek{s\~{w}ma}

\textit{Text in English \textgreek{s\~{w}ma}}

\end{document}

Beware that s{\~{w}}ma would trigger a final sigma. Avoid those useless braces.

Maybe you can try Didot. If you replace bodoni with udidot the output would be


Many thanks for this very helpful answer. I did not know I could get Bodoni directly from Latex. In the past, I had to use a downloaded version. Also, thanks for the information about Baskervald---I did not know that before you pointed it out.

@cfr Perhaps; but you often write comments and then delete them. Subsequently, one's response to them is left dangling. It's quite annoying ;)  Also, it would be good not to leave comments like the one you just did. It shows you spend a lot of time worrying about your "reputation."

@cfr The question was temporarily removed, I guess that the comment got lost in this endeavor.

@Jethro if by 'reputation', you mean se points then, no, you're entirely mistaken. I mean, obviously I'm going to be interested in the claim that baskervald is messing up greek ....

@egreg i guess so. I hit enter and the page disappeared. I try to delete comments when people have read them or when answers supersede them. (I also try to leave a comment indicating this.) I thought we were meant to remove them?
